# Prior Art for Method And System For Improved Network Maintence Scheduling

Tags: prior-art, telecommunications, maintenance, us20120173688

Application # 20120173688
 Primary Filing Category-Telecommunications-455

The system is designed to coordinate planned maintenance on a network in order to prevent collisions and duplicated work from causing outages on any network. Quite often,there have been instances where multiple parties have attempted to upgrade a network and have interfered and overlapped with each other causing the network to go out of service.

My application asserts that this can all be handled intelligently and prevent any chance for duplication of work and network down time on any network. This system also optimizes available resources by efficiently allocating time,resources and personnel to more effectively time manage and perform maintenance on any network.

During my research,I have not seen any prior art that would be similar to the application. 
However,I'm curious if any other  methods and systems currently exist that would prevent the application from being granted.

Comment: This application received a non-final rejection in Dec. The examiner cited US-5,586,254 A 12-1996 Kondo et al. 
*  B US-6,414,955 B1 07-2002 Clare et al.
*  C US-6,751 ,657 B1 06-2004 Zothner, Eric R. 
*  D US-7,395,053 B1 07-2008 Mak et al.  So I assume you mean besides those references. This application is assigned to Lucent, I beleive. If you are one of the inventors or otherwise involved with pursuing this application I'm sure you are aware that you have a duty to tell the USPTO about anything you find that is relevant (negatively) to its patentablity.